# Circumflex Accents on French Keyboards for LaTex

Tags: keyboard-layout

I just changed my computer and my circumflex accents do not work as before. Previously, typing once on the circumflex accent made it appear (^). Tapping directly on a vowel turned it into an accented letter (â). Especially for writing Latex, "^" followed by "{" gave me "^ {".

On my new computer, pressing the circumflex and then directly on a non-vowel button does not appear at all, which forces me to hit the space between the two, and drastically increases my typing time.

It's quite difficult to find a solution because people are rather trying to solve the problem "inverse" (they do not want "^" without letter below ...) ...

If you have a solution, it would help me a lot! Thank you in advance and good day.

Comment: Sorry, but I will comment in English: what keyboard is set in Settings/Region and language under Input Source? (for Settings, click on the little triangle on the task bar, or enter `gnome-control-center` in a terminal.)

Comment: Although your concern is with French Keyboard layout, this site is English only. So, I've translated your question into English.

Comment: Thanks for the translation. I'm sorry, indeed "french (no dead key)" works. The trick was after adding it on the list of possible keyboards does not switch to it automatically. Don't know how I didn't see it before.. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [switch keyboard layout](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html). The *French (alt., no dead keys)* layout turns the <kbd>^</kbd> key to a non-dead key.